# Duplicate information appearing in categories on a Blog site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, categories

I have created a blog site which contains the standard 3 categories.  I have then edited the page for category 1 and have entered text onto the page, however, when i then click onto Category 2, the same text also shows on there??  If I edit/remove it, it is removed from Category 1 also.

Does anybody know where I'm going wrong and how I can remove this 'link'?

Thank you.
Louise